# ngbModal as a generic Confrimation Box

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to create generic confirmation box using ngbmodal, which will be used across the App. In which, Title and message will be passed to the modal from the calling component. I created as a DialogService and added in the entryComponents. Now I am able to show the Confirmation box. But not able to get the result. Below is the code to show the ConfirmationBox component. How to get the value from it

```
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationBoxComponent,{backdrop:"static"})
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = "Message";
    modalRef.componentInstance.confirmationBoxTitle = "Confirmation?"
    modalRef.componentInstance.confirmationmessage = "Do you want to cancel?"
    modalRef.componentInstance.changeRef.markForCheck();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many easy ways of achieving this but I would suggest one that is the simplest and the most effective IMO: resolve modal's `result` promise with the user's choice. This is as simple as doing following in the component representing modal's content (notice `activeModal.close(...)`):

```
<button (click)="activeModal.close(true)">Yes</button>
<button (click)="activeModal.close(false)">No</button>
```

Afterwards you can get back user's answer from the `result` promise of the [NgbModalRef](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal#NgbModalRef) (notice `modalRef.result.then`):

```
open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.confirmationBoxTitle = 'Confirmation?';
    modalRef.componentInstance.confirmationMessage = 'Do you want to cancel?';

    modalRef.result.then((userResponse) => {
      console.log(`User's choice: ${userResponse}`)
    });        
  }
```

You can see all this in action in the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yYIx1m1e2nfK0nxFwYLJ?p=preview