# How to pass data modal Component to parent Component using ng-bootstrap in angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I tried below coding for pass data from modal component to parent component.

**package.json**

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.3"
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal()">Open</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class AppComponent {

   constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

    openModal() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AppModalComponent);
    }
}
```

**app-modal.component.html**

```
<h1>{{data}}</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addMe()"></button>
```

**app-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class AppModalComponent {
    private data: string;
    @Output emitService = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
        this.data = "hello world";
    }

    addMe() {
        this.emitService.next(this.data)
    }
}
```

After emit, how to get data in parent Component (app.component) ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `emitService` `@Output` like so:

```
openModal() {
     const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AppModalComponent);
     modalRef.componentInstance.emitService.subscribe((emmitedValue) => {
         // do sth with emmitedValue
     });
}
```

While the above will work, please note that it is usually easier to just close modal with the value you want to return. This will resolve a promise available on the `modalRef`. More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614501/1418796

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I need to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Line is Wrong
@Output emitService = new EventEmitter();

You Must use @Output()